# "TypeError: Contact is not a constructor" when I check post json data in Postman

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express

When I run node app.js it works, and does not give any error. But when I route localhost:3000/api/contact and post json to check via Postman it gives that error.
I have seen some other releted question but cannot fiqure out.
Here is my app.js

```
//importing modules

var express = require('express');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var bodyparser = require('body-parser');
var cors = require('cors');
var path = require('path');

var app = express();

const route = require('./routes/route');

//connect to mongodb
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/contactlist');

//connection on
mongoose.connection.on('connected',()=>{
    console.log('Database connected');
});

mongoose.connection.on('error',(err)=>{
    if(err)
    {
        console.log('Error in database'+err);
    }
});

//path port
const port = 3000;

//adding middleware
app.use(cors());

//body-parser
app.use(bodyparser.json());

//static path
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'public')));
//add route
app.use('/api',route);

//testing server
app.get('/',(req,res)=>{
    res.send('foobar');
});

app.listen(port,()=>{
     console.log('server is started at port:'+port);
});
```

Here is my route.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();


const Contact = require('../models/contacts');

//get data
router.get('/contacts', (req, res, next)=>{
    Contact.find(function(err, contacts){
        res.json(contacts);
    });
});

//add data
router.post('/contact',(req, res, next)=>{
    let newContact = new Contact({
        first_name: req.body.first_name,
        last_name: req.body.last_name,
        phone_num: req.body.phone_num 
    });

    newContact.save((err, contact)=>{
        if(err)
        {
            res.json({msg: 'Failed to add contact'});
        }
        else
        {
            res.json({msg: 'Contact add succesfuly'});;
        }
    });
});

//delete data
router.delete('/contact/:id', (req, res, next)=>{
    Contact.remove({_id: req.params.id}, function(err, result){
        if(err)
        {
            res.json(err);
        }
        else
        {
            res.json(result);
        }
    });
});
module.exports = router;
```

I am a new node js learner. I cant understand what is the problem please help me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is in `../models/contacts`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the code below:

```
// your schema and model
// should look similar to below
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var ContactSchema = new Schema({
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    phone_num: String
});

const Contact = mongoose.model('Contact', ContactSchema);
module.exports =  Contact;
```

Maybe you forgot to use `mongoose.model`?